# Error when converting xml file

Tags: xml

I wanted to convert my blogger xml file to a wordpress one with the blogger2wordpress application. Now I'm getting these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py", line 716, in __call__
    handler.post(*groups)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/blogger2wordpress/1.342259769852558481/blogger2wordpress.py", line 37, in post
    translator = b2wp.Blogger2Wordpress(input)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/blogger2wordpress/1.342259769852558481/b2wp.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.feed = atom.FeedFromString(self.doc)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/blogger2wordpress/1.342259769852558481/atom/__init__.py", line 1338, in FeedFromString
    return CreateClassFromXMLString(Feed, xml_string)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/blogger2wordpress/1.342259769852558481/atom/__init__.py", line 93, in optional_warn_function
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/blogger2wordpress/1.342259769852558481/atom/__init__.py", line 127, in CreateClassFromXMLString
    tree = ElementTree.fromstring(xml_string)
  File "<string>", line 85, in XML
SyntaxError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 2
```

Someone knows how to solve them?

Comment: Well, what is in line 1, column 2 of your XML file?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an encoding issue. Make sure that your XML file is written using the same codec as the opening application expects (which should be `utf-8`). Otherwise you might run into endianness issues or problems with [BOMs (Byte Order Mark)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: Thanks for answering me Tim. Now I got a xml file which is written in utf-8 coding. I guess this one must be okay, but now I'm getting another error in the Blogger2Wordpress converter:  
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title' Do you understand this error?

Comment: It looks like the converter is looking  for a certain XML tag (which it expects to have an attribute named `title`) can't find that tag in the file (the search returns `None`). And `None` doesn't have any attributes, of course. Are you sure the files are compatible?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know anything about blogger/wordpress or their file formats.